# JQ Group Multiple Files

Tags: json, bash, jq

I have a set of JSON that all contain JSON in the following format:

File 1:

```
{ "host" : "127.0.0.1", "port" : "80", "data": {}}
```

File 2:

```
{ "host" : "127.0.0.2", "port" : "502", "data": {}}
```

File 3:

```
{ "host" : "127.0.0.1", "port" : "443", "data": {}}
```

These files can be rather large, up to several gigabytes.

I want to use JQ or some other bash json processing tool that can merge these json files into one file with a grouped format like so:

```
[{ "host" : "127.0.0.1", "data": {"80": {}, "443" : {}}},
{ "host" : "127.0.0.2", "data": {"502": {}}}]
```

Is this possible with jq and if yes, how could I possibly do this? I have looked at the group_by function in jq, but it seems like I need to combine all files first and then group on this big file. However, since the files can be very large, it might make sense to stream the data and group them on the fly.

Comment: Your files aren't valid JSON...

Comment: It was a typo, it should be valid now. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

With really big files, I'd look into a primarily disk based approach instead of trying to load everything into memory. The following script leverages sqlite's [JSON1](https://www.sqlite.org/json1.html) extension to load the JSON files into a database and generate the grouped results:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

DB=json.db

# Delete existing database if any.
rm -f "$DB"

# Create table. Assuming each host,port pair is unique.
sqlite3 -batch "$DB" <<'EOF'
CREATE TABLE data(host TEXT, port INTEGER, data TEXT,
                  PRIMARY KEY (host, port)) WITHOUT ROWID;
EOF

# Insert the objects from the files into the database.
for file in file*.json; do
    sqlite3 -batch "$DB" <<EOF
INSERT INTO data(host, port, data)
SELECT json_extract(j, '\$.host'), json_extract(j, '\$.port'), json_extract(j, '\$.data')
FROM (SELECT json(readfile('$file')) AS j) as json;
EOF
done

# And display the results of joining the objects Could use
# json_group_array() instead of this sed hackery, but we're trying to
# avoid building a giant string with the entire results. It might still
# run into sqlite maximum string length limits...
sqlite3 -batch -noheader -list "$DB" <<'EOF' | sed '1s/^/[/; $s/,$/]/'
SELECT json_object('host', host,
                   'data', json_group_object(port, json(data))) || ','
FROM data
GROUP BY host
ORDER BY host;
EOF
```

Running this on your sample data prints out:

```
[{"host":"127.0.0.1","data":{"80":{},"443":{}}},
{"host":"127.0.0.2","data":{"502":{}}}]
```

Answer (score 0):

If the goal is really to produce a single ginormous JSON entity, then presumably that entity is still small enough to have a chance of fitting into the memory of some computer, say C.  So there is a good chance of jq being up to the job on C.  At any rate, to utilize memory efficiently, you would:

1. use `inputs` while performing the grouping operation;
2. avoid the built-in `group_by` (since it requires an in-memory sort).

Here then is a two-step candidate using jq, which assumes grouping.jq contains the following program:

```
# emit a stream of arrays assuming that f is always string-valued
def GROUPS_BY(stream; f): 
  reduce stream as $x ({}; ($x|f) as $s | .[$s] += [$x]) | .[];

GROUPS_BY(inputs | .data=.port | del(.port); .host)
| {host: .[0].host, data: map({(.data): {}}) | add}
```

If the JSON files can be captured by `*.json`, you could then consider:

```
jq -n -f grouping.jq *.json | jq -s .
```

One advantage of this approach is that if it fails, you could try using a temporary file to hold the output of the first step, and then processing it later, either by "slurping" it, or perhaps more sensibly distributing it amongst several files, one per `.host`.

### Removing extraneous data

Obviously, if the input files contain extraneous data, you might want to remove it first, e.g. by running

```
for f in *.json ; do
  jq '{host,port}' "$f" | sponge $f
done
```

or by performing the projection in program.jq, e.g. using:

```
GROUPS_BY(inputs | {host, data: .port}; .host)
| {host: .[0].host, data: map( {(.data):{}} )}
```

Comment: sponge.........?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a script which uses jq to solve the problem without requiring more memory than is needed for the largest group. For simplicity:

- it reads *.json and directs output to $OUT as defined at the top of the script.
- it uses `sponge`

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# Requires: sponge

OUT=big.json

/bin/rm -i "$OUT"

if [ -s "$OUT" ] ; then
    echo $OUT already exists
    exit 1
fi

### Step 0: setup

TDIR=$(mktemp -d /tmp/grouping.XXXX)

function cleanup {
  if [ -d "$TDIR" ] ; then
    /bin/rm -r "$TDIR"
  fi
}
trap cleanup EXIT

### Step 1: find the groups

for f in *.json ; do
    host=$(jq -r '.host' "$f")
    echo "$f" >> "$TDIR/$host"
done

for f in $TDIR/* ; do
  echo $f ...
  jq -n 'reduce (inputs | {host, data: {(.port): {} }}) as $in (null; 
     .host=$in.host | .data += [$in.data])' $(cat $f) | sponge "$f"
done

### Step 2: assembly
i=0
echo "[" > $OUT
find $TDIR -type f | while read f ; do
    i=$((i + 1))
    if [ $i -gt 1 ] ; then echo , >> $OUT ; fi
    cat "$f" >> $OUT
done    
echo "]" >> $OUT
```

### Discussion

Besides requiring enough memory to handle the largest group, the main deficiencies of the above implementation are:

1. it assumes that the `.host` string is suitable as a file name.
2. the resultant file is not strictly speaking pretty-printed.

These two issues could however be addressed quite easily with minor modifications to the script without requiring additional memory.

Answer (score 0):

**My propose is:**

```
$ jq '.' file*.jsonl -s  | jq  'group_by(.host)[]|{ host:.[0].host, data:(map( { (.port): {} } ))|add }' | jq '.' -s
[
  {
    "host": "127.0.0.1",
    "data": {
      "80": {},
      "443": {}
    }
  },
  {
    "host": "127.0.0.2",
    "data": {
      "502": {}
    }
  }
]
```

**Explanation:**

First we have several individual files, in our example 3:

```
$ cat file1.jsonl
{ "host" : "127.0.0.1", "port" : "80", "data": {}}

$ cat file2.jsonl
{ "host" : "127.0.0.2", "port" : "502", "data": {}}

$ cat file3.jsonl
{ "host" : "127.0.0.1", "port" : "443", "data": {}}
```

Next, all files file*.json are joined as one, with this command:

```
$  jq '.' file*.jsonl
{
  "host": "127.0.0.1",
  "port": "80",
  "data": {}
}
{
  "host": "127.0.0.2",
  "port": "502",
  "data": {}
}
{
  "host": "127.0.0.1",
  "port": "443",
  "data": {}
}
```

Next, we put all objects into an array (with -s parameter) :

```
$  jq '.' file*.jsonl -s
[
  {
    "host": "127.0.0.1",
    "port": "80",
    "data": {}
  },
  {
    "host": "127.0.0.2",
    "port": "502",
    "data": {}
  },
  {
    "host": "127.0.0.1",
    "port": "443",
    "data": {}
  }
]
```

Next, we group by .host field: (Note the output is 2 arrays contained into one array)

```
$ jq '.' file*.jsonl -s  | jq  'group_by(.host)'
[
  [
    {
      "host": "127.0.0.1",
      "port": "80",
      "data": {}
    },
    {
      "host": "127.0.0.1",
      "port": "443",
      "data": {}
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      "host": "127.0.0.2",
      "port": "502",
      "data": {}
    }
  ]
]
```

Next, we avoid the outer array with this command: (now we have only 2 arrays)

```
$ jq '.' file*.jsonl -s  | jq  'group_by(.host)[]'
[
  {
    "host": "127.0.0.1",
    "port": "80",
    "data": {}
  },
  {
    "host": "127.0.0.1",
    "port": "443",
    "data": {}
  }
]
[
  {
    "host": "127.0.0.2",
    "port": "502",
    "data": {}
  }
]
```

Next, we begin to build the final object structure, with the first field "host":

Note the "host" field can be named differently, ex: "my_hosts".

This first field was built with the member 0 of each of our 2 arrays.

```
$ jq '.' file*.jsonl -s  | jq  'group_by(.host)[]|{ host:.[0].host }'
{
  "host": "127.0.0.1"
}
{
  "host": "127.0.0.2"
}
```

Next, we begin tu build the second field "data" in our final structure:

In this case "." is each one of the arrays that cointains the grouped objects.

Note here the fieldname "data" cuould be named as "my_data".

```
$ jq '.' file*.jsonl -s  | jq  'group_by(.host)[]|{ host:.[0].host ,data:(.) }'

{
  "host": "127.0.0.1",
  "data": [
    {
      "host": "127.0.0.1",
      "port": "80",
      "data": {}
    },
    {
      "host": "127.0.0.1",
      "port": "443",
      "data": {}
    }
  ]
}
{
  "host": "127.0.0.2",
  "data": [
    {
      "host": "127.0.0.2",
      "port": "502",
      "data": {}
    }
  ]
}
```

Next, we iterate of each one of the arrays (map) and we are going building small objects with one fied named as the port and its value is {} (an empty object):

Note here the fieldname .port is between "()",  is an expression to use the value of the port as key.

Note the field "data" is an array of objects.

```
$ jq '.' file*.jsonl -s  | jq  'group_by(.host)[]|{ host:.[0].host ,data:( map({(.port):{} }) ) }'
{
  "host": "127.0.0.1",
  "data": [
    {
      "80": {}
    },
    {
      "443": {}
    }
  ]
}
{
  "host": "127.0.0.2",
  "data": [
    {
      "502": {}
    }
  ]
}
```

Next, we concatenate all the objects in the field "data" with the command "add":

Note how data has been converted from an array to an object (in this case a dictionary).

```
$ jq '.' file*.jsonl -s  | jq  'group_by(.host)[]|{ host:.[0].host ,data:( map({(.port):{} })|add ) }'
{
  "host": "127.0.0.1",
  "data": {
    "80": {},
    "443": {}
  }
}
{
  "host": "127.0.0.2",
  "data": {
    "502": {}
  }
}
```

Finally, we can display the results in compact format (one object by line) with the parameter (-c):

```
$ jq '.' file*.jsonl -s  | jq  'group_by(.host)[]|{ host:.[0].host ,data:( map({(.port):{} })|add ) }' -c
{"host":"127.0.0.1","data":{"80":{},"443":{}}}
{"host":"127.0.0.2","data":{"502":{}}}
```

If you want the results in compact format all into an array, only add jq '.' -s -c  to the pipe:

```
$ jq '.' file*.jsonl -s  | jq  'group_by(.host)[]|{ host:.[0].host ,data:( map({(.port):{} })|add ) }' -c | jq '.' -s -c
[{"host":"127.0.0.1","data":{"80":{},"443":{}}},{"host":"127.0.0.2","data":{"502":{}}}]
```

I hope  this explanation can be useful for you.